# how to create trackballevent in android custom adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

i am using following code to create custom adapter for listview.
now i want to use trackball click event in it but i dont know how to do that can any one help me out in creating ontracballevent in custom adapter?
i have tried writing few lines  but not able to solve it.

```
public  class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context context;
         int pos;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {

          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ViewHolder holder;

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_contentposts, null);
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
```

//click functionality
}
                });

```
 MotionEvent event= MotionEvent.CREATOR.createFromParcel(null);
            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //display click message
            }
            convertView.onTrackballEvent(event);





 return convertView;
        }

  class ViewHolder {
          TextView textLine;
          TextView textLine2;
          TextView PostedByAndPostedOn;
          ImageButton ImgButton;

        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return ad_id.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
          return ad_id[position];
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapters have nothing to do with "ontracballevent". You either need to subclass ListView or handle it in your activity.

Comment: but convertView.onTrackballEvent is available in adapter which i am using for listview..

Comment: Then you are going to have to subclass whatever your rows are, override `onTrackballEvent()` in those, and hope that whatever it is you are trying to do is possible.